# DateTime diff returns me 0 when the compared DateTimes are different

Tags: php, datetime, diff, datediff, date-difference

I would like to return the hours and minutes of difference between two dates. The problem is that the result of the diff method returns me a diff of 0 (same DateTimes).

Here is my actual code :

```php
$last_vote_date = new DateTime(\Auth::user()->last_vote_at);
$next_vote_date = $last_vote_date;
$next_vote_date->add(new DateInterval('PT3H'));
$diff = $next_vote_date->diff($last_vote_date, true);
$vote_hours = $diff->format('%h h %I m');
```

I debugged my vars. `$last_vote_date` is the correct DateTime.
`$next_vote_date` is a correct DateTime representing the last vote date + 3 hours.
However all the properties of the DateInterval object that diff returns are all 0 :

```php
DateInterval Object ( [y] => 0 [m] => 0 [d] => 0 [h] => 0 [i] => 0 [s] => 0 [f] => 0 [weekday] => 0 [weekday_behavior] => 0 [first_last_day_of] => 0 [invert] => 0 [days] => 0 [special_type] => 0 [special_amount] => 0 [have_weekday_relative] => 0 [have_special_relative] => 0 )
```

I really don't understand what's going wrong as my two DateTime objects being compared are different and are exactly the value I want.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `$next_vote_date = $last_vote_date` you are basically copying a reference. Meaning any changes you make to `$next_vote_date` will affect `$last_vote_date`. The quick way to deal with this is to copy the object:

```php
$last_vote_date = new DateTime(\Auth::user()->last_vote_at);
$next_vote_date = clone $last_vote_date;
$next_vote_date->add(new DateInterval('PT3H'));
$diff = $next_vote_date->diff($last_vote_date, true);
$vote_hours = $diff->format('%h h %I m');
```